# how to display unicode character in web browser control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I want to display unicode character for different languages in web browser control of WPF
but it displays special characters

is there any setting I have to set in web browser control ?

Comment: Have you tried HTML Entity (hex)?  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: To down-voters: why? It's actually a good question, considering that still not all websites send `Content-Type: text/html; charset=` in their HTTP response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us how your load the content into `WebBrowser`. If you navigate to a URL, make sure the server sends correct `charset` encoding as part of `Content-Type`in HTTP response headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

If you have no control over the server, and the server doesn't specify the charset in the response content (a bad manner), you'd need to manually set the encoding using DOM [document.charset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property, once the document has been loaded. This property is not exposed by the WPF version of `WebBrowser`, so you'd need to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic domDocument = webBrowser.Document;
domDocument.charset = "Windows-1252";
```

I'm using "Windows-1252" as an example here, you'd actually need to experiment to find the correct value for a particular web page, if the server doesn't specify it. Load the page into full IE, go to View/Encoding/More menu and find what works for that page.

That said, if you navigate to a string (with `NavigateToString`), it should support Unicode characters out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the header by adding `Accept-Language` in Navigate method.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172998

SO Link

[How to set Accept and Accept-Language header fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224454/how-to-set-accept-and-accept-language-header-fields)

Comment: `Accept-Language` header doesn't affect the actual character encoding. `Content-Type` does.