# Webbrowser control displays garbled unicode text

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, browser

I am using a webbrowser control in my C# winform application. The Html page consists of Unicode Urdu Text. When i open the Html page in Internet Explorer it displays correctly. However when i load the same page in webbrowser control the text displayed is a mix of Urdu characters and other garbled text. The Meta tag contains document Encoding

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Please see this below link

[how to display unicode character in web browser control in WPF][1]

Hope it help.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315078/how-to-display-unicode-character-in-web-browser-control-in-wpf

Comment: In this document the content type is set correctly.

Comment: It could be compatibility issue, try to force IE to run in latest browser emulation mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874565/how-to-set-ie9-by-default-for-web-browser/15883250#15883250