# Issues with converting a piece of CURL to C#

Tags: c#, curl

This CURL works:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-User: bryanoliver" -H "X-Auth-Expires: 1406485297" -H "X-Auth-Key: 946ddd08f5fbcb3ddb0c91e3785f0630" "-H" "Accept: application/xml" "https://cloud.technologies.com/api/jobs/1"
```

This C# fails not sure what I have missed:

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://cloud.technologies.com/api/jobs/1");
request.ContentType = "Accept: application/xml";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers["X-Auth-User"] = "bryanoliver";
request.Headers["X-Auth-Expires"] = "1406485297";
request.Headers["X-Auth-Key"] = "946ddd08f5fbcb3ddb0c91e3785f0630";
string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqstr.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: How does it fail? You have not declared request in the example, it does not even compile.

Comment: Define "fails."  Is there an exception or error of some kind?  Error messages have an uncanny tendency to provide useful information.  If there's no error, when you debug this at what point does it behave differently than you expect?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: I don't think that is proper way to set the Accept header. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224454/how-to-set-accept-and-accept-language-header-fields).

Comment: @keyboardP you also need to initialize `buffer` before first use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with the following

```
public static void ElementalGetRequest(String url, String md5url, String elementalUser, String elementalApiKey, out String Result)
{

    TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
    int timestamp = (int)t.TotalSeconds;

    string hash = CalculateMD5Hash(elementalApiKey + (CalculateMD5Hash(md5url + elementalUser + elementalApiKey + Convert.ToString(timestamp))));

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Auth-User: "+elementalUser);
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Expires: " + Convert.ToString(timestamp));
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Key: " + hash);

    WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string serverResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    Result = serverResponse;

}
```