# 415 Unsupported Media Type; Angular2 to API

Tags: api, angular, http-post

i am new to angular 2 and i'm facing a problem which i cant find a solution:
When i try to post from angular 2 to API i get - 415 unsupported media type.

Angular 2 code:

```
 onSubmit(value: any) {
    // console.log(value.message);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let creds = 'statusuknown';
    let body = JSON.stringify(creds);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:1318/api/ActionItem', creds)
      .subscribe(
        () => {console.log('Success')},
        err => {console.error(err)}
      );
  }
```

And my controller code:

```
 // POST api/actionitem
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionItem Post( [FromBody]string str)// _id, string _status)
        {
            ActionItem item = new ActionItem( 313, str);
            return item;
        }
```

when i change the controller code to not get data from body it works but refers NULL.

My API call screenshot:
[image]
Please help & let me know if more details needed.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-descriptive: You send JSON and the server tells you _"I don't support JSON"_

Comment: @zeroflagL that makes sense, although im not sure ,when i use POSTMAN to post to my api it goes thru and return the value i need. how do i make my api support JSON?

Comment: I assume you don't set a `Content-Type` header when you use Postman. You only send a string in your example, so you actually don't need JSON. You can send `creds` directly.

Comment: @zeroflagL i do set content-type when i use postman , otherwise it doesn't work, looks like it has something to do with my localhost use. i was informed to try post using a server and it will work! exactly how postman works!

Comment: I see. Then the problem could be CORS. That would mean that the server needs additional (or a different) configuration.

Comment: as for now that seems to be the problem, i will use server with iis and will post afterwards

Answer (score 1):

[image]You defined headers, but didn't use it. Change your code to

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:1318/api/ActionItem', body, options).map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(
        () => {console.log('Success')}
      );
```

Comment: ,still same issue - unsupported media type

Comment: still no good, can i supply more info to give you better view of this issue?

Comment: unfortunately rechecked and it didn't solve, i can tell you that my get does work if that helps you to understand better.

Comment: could you try this url instead? http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, so we make sure that's the problem not in your api

Comment: here is a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/kO2i4wf5fovx0TeT3c7A?p=preview Please check and confirm that your code looks the same

Comment: 201 and i get response id 101, can i add string to Body and link it to my api? or the api is the problem

Comment: if your angular code looks the same, then the problem in your api. First you should check your code and make my plunker example works in your app, then change url to your api and see if it's still doesn't work

Comment: your code works for me , when i changed the URL to my api i get - 415 unsupported media type., so i guess problem is my api but i still dont know what is the problem because its not in the code probably

Comment: what's language of your backend?

Comment: language is c# but i tried my code and its fine, the request to post is failing

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d 'statusuknown' http://localhost:1318/api/ActionItem Does it work?

Comment: remove all from your api endpoint, including params and leave only "return 'test'"

Comment: return "test" doesn't work and i get same unsupported media type

Comment: your api doesn't accept 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: try let body = JSON.stringify({}); with return 'test'

Comment: taht the code right now , let body-JSON.stringify({})

Comment: make a screen of headers from your api. f12->networks->your_api_call->headers

Comment: i didnt understand this comment, can u explain better? i will do it later tonight. thanks

Comment: check attached to this question file

Comment: and response tab too please

Comment: i didnt understand the curl answer. posted screenshot in quetion

Comment: you need to set Accept header, it should be like this 'Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*' I'm not familiar with C#, check these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224454/how-to-set-accept-and-accept-language-header-fields

Comment: @Orenger did you fix your issue?

Comment: @Euridice01 yes issue was fixed, i odnt think its relevant for today as it gets fixed by itself, problem with header

Answer (score 0):

use header and body also in http request. in cread use value parameter of onSubmit function.

use following code

```
let creds=JSON.Stringify(value);

this.http.post('http://localhost:1318/api/ActionItem', creds, options)
     .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
       this.result = res;
       console.log(this.result);
     });
```