# Angular API 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angular, api

I am getting the data from the API to put it in a table, and I am having an error.

```
constructor(private marketListService: MaxDigitalService ) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.dataSource = new DataGridDataSource({
      load: params => {
        return this.marketListService
          .GetMarketListDaysSupply()
          .pipe(
            map(x => {
              console.log(x)
            })
          )
          .toPromise();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [415 Unsupported Media Type; Angular2 to API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473474/415-unsupported-media-type-angular2-to-api)

Comment: Already tried it but no. Thank you for helping.